# Is it ok to use atomics to reduce locking in a read dominant multithread program?

Tags: c++, multithreading, atomic

Recently, I found myself often in a situation that shared data get read a lot, but written rarely, so I begin to wonder is it possible to speed up the sync a little bit.

Take the following as an example, in which mutiple threads occasionally write the data, a single thread frequently read the data, all synched with a normal mutex.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>

using namespace std;

unordered_map<int, int> someData({{1,10}});
mutex mu;

void writeData(){
    while(true){
        {
            lock_guard<mutex> lock(mu);
            int r = rand()%10;
            someData[1] = r;
            printf("data changed to %d\n", r);
        }
        usleep(rand()%100000000 + 100000000);
    }
}

void readData(){
    while(true){
        {
            lock_guard<mutex> lock(mu);
            for(auto &i:someData){
                printf("%d:%d\n", i.first, i.second);
            }
        }
        usleep(100);
    }

}

int main() {
    thread writeT1(&writeData2);
    thread writeT2(&writeData2);
    thread readT(&readData2);
    readT.join();
}
```

using normal lock mechanism, every read requires a lock, and I'm thinking to speed up to a single atomic read **in most cases**:

```cpp
unordered_map<int, int> someData({{1,10}});
mutex mu;
atomic_int dataVersion{0};

void writeData2(){
    while(true){
        {
            lock_guard<mutex> lock(mu);
            dataVersion.fetch_add(1, memory_order_acquire);
            int r = rand()%10;
            someData[1] = r;
            printf("data changed to %d\n", r);
        }
        usleep(rand()%100000000 + 100000000);
    }
}

void readData2(){
    mu.lock();
    int versionCopy = dataVersion.load();
    auto dataCopy = someData;
    mu.unlock();

    while(true){
        if (versionCopy != dataVersion.load(memory_order_relaxed)){
            lock_guard<mutex> lock(mu);
            versionCopy = dataVersion.load(memory_order_relaxed);
            dataCopy = someData;
        }
        else{
            for(auto &i:dataCopy){
                printf("%d:%d\n", i.first, i.second);
            }
            usleep(100);
        }

    }

}
```

The data type `unordered_map` here is just an example, it could be any type, and I'm not looking for a pure lock-free algorithm, as that might be a whole other story. Just for a normal lock based sync, in a situation that most operation is read, using a trick like this, **is it logically ok? Are there any established approaches for this?**

**[edit]**

- I'm aware of the **shared mutex**, but it isn't really the situation that I was talking about. firstly shared lock is not cheap, probably more expensive than the plain mutex, certainly heavier than atomics; secondly, in the example I showed a single reading thread which can't take much advantage of it.
- I was interested particularly in the locking operation cost. Reducing blocking, critical section sure is the first thing to look at in a real case, but I wasn't targeting that here.
- The **unordered_map data type is just an example**, not looking for a data structure that better suits for a specific task, or a lock free algorithm, the data type could be anything.
- sleep time is to demonstrate that **read happens way much more than write**, to a degree that we begin to not so care the extra lock and copy time in the if block.

Thanks~

Comment: You might also be interested in [`std::shared_mutex`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/shared_mutex).  It allows you to have multiple readers to all acquire the lock is shared mode and then then allow the writer to get exclusive access so it can do it's write when it needs to.

Comment: @NathanOliver-ReinstateMonica yeah im aware of shared_mutex, but at least in my test in linux, a shared_lock for read is not cheap, actually it is slower than the plain mutex, of course, it will allow multiple reading thread, but that isn't really regards to example I posed

Comment: Spin locks might be an option.

Comment: Did you try to measure the performance of both approaches? http://quick-bench.com/

Comment: In your second example you still use locks and add an additional overhead using atomics. There are really efficient patterns that allow you to avoid locks, but most probable that you would have to reimplement the container. See "C++ Concurrency in Action" by Anthony Williams.

Comment: *in a situation that shared data get read a lot, but written rarely*  Are you seeing any reader threads blocking and waiting for other reader threads that are actually reading the data?  If not, and all your reads are from a single thread, there's nothing gained in a more complex locking scheme.

Comment: @DmitryKuzminov yes I still used lock, but as I said write is rarely happened, so that additional lock is rarely required, most time it goes into the else block

Comment: @IvanB You should provide a proper benchmark... And also clarify the problem you are facing. What's the kind of data you are writing/reading? What's *read a lot* and *rarely written*? In your example, you are reading about 10 times more than you're writing, so you're basically making a whole copy of your data every 10 reads...

Comment: @Anrew yeah, I got what you mean, critical section time is the most important part, the possible locking performace gained compared to that is probably nothing in reality, im just curious

Comment: @Ptaq666 & Holt :pardon me that i don't know a proper way to bench this, I was essentialy benching a mutex lock/unlock vs an atomic load, and I think that is needless to say? I was most curious in that, if the logic is correct. The example is 10-100x more writes than read, and yes after that a copy is made, but it is just to illustrate the situation, could make it 100000x more reads than writes, just a chance that makes we no longer care about the time cost in the lock and copy block

Comment: @IvanB *"I was essentialy benching a mutex lock/unlock vs an atomic load, and I think that is needless to say?"* - Well, not really. If you have, as in your example, a single thread that locks/unlocks the mutex without almost no locks for the writer, then the overhead of the mutex is probably unoticeable. If you have multiple threads, but are using, e.g., a shared_mutex, then this is probably also insignificant. [...]

Comment: @IvanB [...] *"could make it 100000x more reads than writes,"* - Then your question should reflect that. Furthermore, if your object is huge, then a copy is not insignificant, so having irregular duration in the read might not be what you want... For me, your question is too broad as it is currently written.

Comment: You use sleep for 100 milliseconds. That's around 100,000 times more than any synchronization mechanism might take. I think your question is about waking up your reading thread upon data change and not about synchronization. Look into std::condition_variable.

Comment: @Holt thanks, I'll try to update the question to clarify that

Answer (score 0):

You are storing the data in an unordered_map.  What guarantees does the unordered_map class make about concurrent access for readers & writers.  If it is unhappy with that prospect, the atomics are not your friend.

In most (every?) OS, locking primitives themselves are handled with atomics in the uncontested case; only reverting to a kernel when contested.  With that in mind, you are best to minimize the amount of code while the lock is held, so your first loop should be:

```
    int r = rand()%10;
    mu.lock();
    someData[1] = r;
    mu.unlock();
    printf("data changed to %d\n", r);
```

I don't know how you would fix the read side, but if you chose a friendlier data store, you could minimize access to it in the same way.

Comment: hi, thanks for the reply. I guess I wasn't clear, unordered_map is just an example, the data type could be any, and of course optimization could be made regards that choice, but that isn't what was asking.  and yes print out of the lock scope will reduce the critical section, but 1. it's just a demonstrating here 2. all I was actually trying to target is the synchronization cost (that is the cost of mutex lock/unlock vs atomic load), rather than minimize critical section in a specific problem(yep that might be most importatnt in real problem). I will update the question to clarify that

Answer (score 0):

I will first try to describe my own understanding of your idea:

1. Frequent reads, occasional write.
2. Locks are expensive ... should be benchmarked, try [`std::shared_mutex`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/shared_mutex) or [Slim Reader/Writer SRW Locks - Windows only](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sync/slim-reader-writer--srw--locks), or some other *slim* implementation, which usually use some cheap and optimistic (atomic/spin-lock) mechanism, that has little-to-no impact in case of no collision (no writer most of the time).
3. You don't seem to care how old/recent your copy is. That is acceptable for some informative performance counters, but I would think twice about that - it is not something somebody else having to maintain your code would expect or even think about. The consequences can be catastrophic.
4. You only access the writable data under the lock, read a copy you create holding the lock. That means your approach is *safe* from simple threading synchronization view, except the above point (readers working with old data, multiple readers can have different copies ... is it worth it?).

Anyway, you should really try to benchmark first and then try to find better solution which somebody else already wrote (slim rw-locks), before even attemting to come-up with your own synchronization mechanism (that is generally very hard to do correctly).

**EDIT:** Found some article with concreate shared_mutex implementation using std::atomic:

[Code Project: We make a std::shared_mutex 10 times faster](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1183423/We-make-a-std-shared-mutex-times-faster)

[Coliru test here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/11c191b06aeb5fb6)

Comment: thanks, I agree with most of your comment. Yes, as you said, the extra copy cost may not suit for every situation. I sure have benched some  sync mechanism, shared_mutex is much slower than even pure mutex (in linux, windows I heard is different), no much better for pthread read/write lock as well, and all these are platform specific, and way slower than atomic load. I guess I better to include these in question. I totally agree with your last sentence, actually the main reason I asked here is that I believe that there already exists one, and I don't trust myself :)